# How to refer to a cell in the same column at given row?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function

I would like to get a cell in a particular row above the current cell.
This is to be used in conditional formatting, so I can't specify a particular cell, e.g. `A$4`—the reference would be the same for whole range.

What I need is something like:

```
GET_CELL_AT( COLUMN(CURRENT_CELL), 4 )
```

What I use it for is to color a cell red if it's bigger than a treshold in the other cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved with:

```
=INDIRECT( ADDRESS( 4, COLUMN() ) )
```

`ADDRESS` gives me a string like "$A$1" and `INDIRECT` makes it a cell reference.